# How do I maintain grid system when using affix in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, width, sticky, affix

I am using Bootstrap 3 and affix in a responsive website but when I scroll up the fixed column of text on the left looses its width and expands to the full width of the screen.

I think I am missing something?

Demo here: http://www.jhurleydesign.com/simplyconfectionery/weddings.html

Answer (score 2):

The `affix` component uses `position:fixed` so it removes the affixed element from the flow of the page. This is why the Bootstrap docs (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) state..

> "you must provide CSS for the positioning of your content"

Here's a working example that may help:

http://www.bootply.com/100983

You'll see that it provides CSS for the `.affix-top` and `.affix` classes.

Comment: Thanks - I have done as you suggest and it works but now I am getting a judery effect when it hits the bottom and when I reduce width of browser down to mobile size it disables the sticky effect which is good - but when I open the browser out again the effect remains disabled. any ideas?